# Corrupt New Android Project in Eclipse on Mac OSX 10.9.4

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt, is-empty

Corrupt New Android Project in Eclipse on Mac OSX 10.9.4

**Problem:**

*) New > Project > Android Application Project > ...

*) Upon clicking 'Finish', a project is created, but is obviously corrupt/incomplete, wizard dialog does not close.

*) Project missing res/layout/ and src/ files (and perhaps others)

**From ADT (bundled Eclipse):**

*) Download ADT Bundle: https: //dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702.zip

*) Extract/Move to /opt/adt

*) Using Eclipse (Juno) in /opt/adt/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

**From Eclipse, adding plugin:**

*) Download Eclipse (Luna) eclipse-standard-luna-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

*) Extract/Move to /opt/eclipse

*) Using Eclipse (Luna) in /opt/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

*) Help > Install New Software > Add > https: //dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ > 23.0.2.1259578

*) Eclipse Restart > point to /opt/adt/sdk

**Attempted (unsuccessfully) Other Solutions:**

*Install Software:*

*) Install All software via Android SDK Manager (tools, api, extras)

*Install Updates Manually:*

*) Help > Install new software > "Eclipse Project Updates" > All ...

*) https : //dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (not http : //dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

*Uninstall and Reinstall adt/software:*

*) Eclipse > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Uninstall ... > Finish > Restart

*Different versions/sources manually:*

(stackoverflow.com/ questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt)
*) Download http : //dl.google.com/android/ADT-23.0.2.zip, 22.3.0, ...

*) Help > Install new software > Add > Archive > ...zip

*Different Activity Types / Combinations:*

*) Blank Activity, Empty Activity, Blank with Fragment, ...

*) API 14, API 20, API 21, ...

**Specific References:**

*Null Pointer Exception:*

stackoverflow.com/ questions/23577131/creating-a-new-android-project-in-eclipse-adt-gives-a-nullpointerexception-mac

*Similar via Windows Machine:*

stackoverflow.com/ questions/11492585/cannot-create-a-new-android-project-using-eclipse

*Similar failure, but restricted to activity creation:*

stackoverflow.com/ questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity
stackoverflow.com/ questions/11260619/eclipse-juno-wont-create-android-activity

*Perhaps same issue:*

stackoverflow.com/ questions/22232836/eclipse-android-project-not-creating-blank-activity

*Issue Tracking Possibly same issue:*

https : //code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=66647

*No clear acknowledgment of issue:*

http : //tools.android.com/knownissues

**Hello World:**

https : //developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I actually have a working xubuntu android environment setup using these precise same steps.
I have developed for Android on a Mac in the past, but this is a new problem for me.
Running via command line works, and so does Android Studio, so this seems Eclipse specific.

(SO won't allow screenshots, or more than 2 links)

Comment: Facing the exact same problem on Mac OS 10.10.1 .. sigh.. was hoping for some answer to this !